# Defining and incrementing a variable in bash

Tags: bash, scripts

I've something like this:

```
declare -r constant1=0
declare -r constant2=0

for xx in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
do  
    constant1=$((constant1 + 1))
    for yy in 8 7 3 9 3 9 2 8 4 4
    do
        constant2=$((constant2 + 1))
        if [ $constant1 == $constant2 ]; then
            something here bla bla
        fi
    done
done
```

But it's giving me an error, namely:

```
line 6: constant1: readonly variable
```

How do I go about fixing this?

Basically, I want the "    do something here bla bla" to run whenever constant1 = constant2. that is, [xx,yy] = [1,8],[2,7], etc

Comment: why have you changed your original question?

Comment: Take a look at `help declare` and option `-r`.

Comment: @heemayl, I changed because I add the "do" after incrementing the constant, which is not what I want, I think.

Comment: -1 You have at least two syntax errors, and your variable names are not consistent with the error you give.

Comment: Use: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @Cyrus, thank you! That's an amazing site, I've fixed a few mistakes in OP. It's still giving me the same error though, sadly. I've bookmarked your site for future use, thank you.

Comment: The answer is in @Cyrus's first comment, check `help declare`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify `constant1` and `constant2`, you shouldn't declare them as read-only (that's what `declare -r` does). And if you want to operate of pairs of variables, you should consider using arrays:

```
array1=(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
array2=(8 7 3 9 3 9 2 8 4 4)

for i in ${!array1[@]}
do
    echo "${array1[i]}" "${array2[i]}"
done
```